# Tableau stacked bar graph back to back axis

Tags: tableau-api

Tableau experts!

I am trying to visualize some survey data to show a dashboard like this http://irp.dpb.cornell.edu/tableau_visual/3281.

Could anyone please let me know how to:

1) display the answers in two back to back axis, so that "very important" and "somewhat important" stay on one side of 0, and "not important" stays on the other side of 0?

2) display "very important" etc. on graph instead of showing the percentage? When I clicked to add label to graph, the percentage is displayed on each color bar.

Thanks a lot, May

Comment: Without seeing your data and how it is structured, it will be very hard to help you. Can you update your post with that information?

Comment: I followed the detailed instructions on this link .Likert Scales — The Final Word? – Data Revelations. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

1) Assuming, a dimension called performance contains the given three values - 'not important', 'somewhat important', and 'not important'. A calculated field can be created to show different performance on the different sides of the axis. Let's call it direction =
***if performance = "somewhat important" or performance = "very important" then 1 else -1 end***

Multiply direction with percentage value to create another calculated field and add that to the sheet.